# Table Types in Snowflake vs Teradata

Tags: teradata, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I was trying to look at the alternative's to different table types in Teradata compared to SnowFlake.

From Snowflake documentation,

VOLATILE TABLE alternative are TEMPORARY TABLE
GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE alternative are TRANSIENT TABLE

But in Snowflake, I am able to create both Volatile Table and Global Temp Tables. Not sure how it is allowing or if these also exists. If yes then what are the differences

Answer (score 0):

Snowflake only has permanent (the default), temporary and transient table types.

However, Snowflake has implemented a number of synonyms for temporary in order to make migration for other DBMSs: [CREATE TABLE optional parameters](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-table.html#optional-parameters)

Comment: Is there any alternative for Teradata's Global Temporary Table in Snowflake. Tables whose DDL's are retained across session but data in the table is only available in the current session!

Comment: Did you read the documentation I linked to? Which features of the 3 available Snowflake table types are you unsure about?

Comment: No, Global Temp Tables don't exists in Snowflake.